# Parse error: syntax error in concatenation PHP

Tags: php, loops

```
<?php  
    for ($i=$j=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    <div class='card 
    <?php 
         if($i<3){
             echo "delay" . $j += 5; 
         } 
    ?>'>
}?>
```

I tried the above code but got syntax error.

my desire output is like this

```
<div class="box delay5">
<div class="box delay10">
<div class="box">
<div class="box">
```

Comment: Didnt close php tags before printing html

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must hide the whole PHP code like this.

```
 <?php   
      for ($i=$j=0; $i<5; $i++) { 
 ?>

      <div class='card 
          <?php 
              if($i<3){ 
                  echo "delay" . $j += 5; 
             } 
          ?>
      '>

 <?php } ?>
```

not nice but it will goes his socialism way.

Answer (score 0):

**close php tags correctly.**

```
<?php
for ($i = $j = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
{

 ?>

<div class='card <?php if ($i < 3) { echo "delay" . $j += 5; } ?>'>

<?php   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
    for ($i=$j=0; $i<5; $i++) {
?>
    <div class='card'>
<?php 
         if($i<3){
             echo "delay" . $j += 5; 
         } 
     }
?>
```